# How to get the selected value from select box in html

Tags: javascript

i want to get the selected option from select box.I have this code:

```
<select id="sel">
<option selected>Seciniz</option>
    <%for(int i=1;i<k+1;i++){kullancounter++; %>
<option class="up"><%=ka[i] %></option>
    <%} %>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="katsec()" value="Ekle">
               <script>
    function katsec(){
        alert('asd');
        var a=document.getElementById('sel').value;
        alert(a);
        document.getElementById('tak').innerHTML=a;
    }
        </script>
```

but it opens alert but there is nothing in alert.What should i do?Thanks

Comment: That's not the proper way to retrieve the selected value via javascript. The question has been answered multiple times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript

Comment: you missed value attribute in option tag. write <option class="up" value="<%=ka[i] %>" ><%=ka[i] %></option>

Comment: @HardikBhalani: If the `value` attribute is not present, the text of the `<option>` is taken as value.

Comment: I verified It is not like that, I checked in IE8

Comment: I found the solution from link that @RaulRene sent.Thanks you all a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers - namely, Internet Explorer - doesn't handle the `value` property of `<select>`s correctly. There's a workaround that work for every browser, though:

```
function katsec(){
    var sel = document.getElementById('sel'),
        idx = sel.selectedIndex,
        val = idx > -1 ? sel.options[sel].text : '';
    alert(val);
    document.getElementById('tak').innerHTML = val;
}
```